# HTML code not working and browser literally displaying the html code

Tags: html, error-handling

So I downloaded Microsoft Expression Web 4 and introduced this code in the editor:

```
<!doctype html><html dir="ltr" lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>New Tab</title><style>body {background: #FFFFFF;margin: 0;}
#backgroundImage {border: none;height: 100%;pointer-events: none;position: fixed;top: 0;visibility: hidden;width: 100%;}
[show-background-image] #backgroundImage {visibility: visible;}</style></head><body><iframe id="backgroundImage" src=""></iframe><ntp-app></ntp-app><script type="module" src="new_tab_page.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome://resources/css/text_defaults_md.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="shared_vars.css"></body></html>
```

with all the indents, but when I preview it in Microsoft edge, it literally displays this code instead of the web page that should be generated by it. What's wrong? I literally copied pasted this code from the source code of the google page. Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: Well is it an HTML file? What is it saved as?

Comment: Can I ask why you are using that old editor?

Comment: Yeah it's saved as .html

Comment: What editor should I use then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because as you've said, you put it in the editor and by default the **Design** tab is active. In this product they provide WYSIWYG functionality, so what you see in the editor is how it would show in the browser. Select the **Code** tab at the bottom and then paste the HTML code.